# Populating parse object in picker view with swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uipickerview

Hope someone can help?
I have two queries on a single view.
The first populates a table that works as intended.
The second query I want to populate a UIPickerView and this is causing me grief :(

I can see the results in the println statement
If someone can help it would be greatly appreciated

Here is the code
    class ProfileVC: UIViewController {

```
var pickerString = NSArray() as AnyObject as [String]
var industryValue = [getIndustries]()

@IBOutlet weak var StoredIndustries: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var countryControl: UIPickerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Industries")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // query successful - display number of rows found
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) industries")

            // print sentences found
            for object in objects {

                let retrievedIndustries = object["Sector"] as NSString
                self.industryValue += [getIndustries(parseIndustry:"\(retrievedIndustries)")]
                println("\(retrievedIndustries) ")
            }

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error) \(error.userInfo!)")
        }

        self.StoredIndustries.reloadData()
    }

    var query2 = PFQuery(className: "CountryLanguage")

    query2.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) Countries")
            var counter: Int = 0
            for object in objects {
                var storeString = ""
                let retrievedLanguages = object["Language"] as NSString
                let retrievedCode = object["Ccode"] as NSString
                println("\(retrievedLanguages)" + " - " + "\(retrievedCode)")
                storeString = ("\(retrievedLanguages)" + " - " + "\(retrievedCode)")
                self.pickerString.insert(storeString, atIndex:counter)
                counter = counter + 1
            }
            //self.countryControl.reloadAllComponents()
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should uncomment `self.countryControl.reloadAllComponents()` inside your `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`, so that your `UIPickerView can refresh.

Also you need to make your UIViewControl extends the `UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate`. Do the following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate {
}
```

Then in the `viewDidLoad()` method, set the delegate and datasource of your `UIPickerView`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    countryControl.delgete = self
    countryControl.dataSource = self
......}
```

Also you should implement the following delegate methods for `UIPickerView`:

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
   return self.pickerString.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

    return self.pickerString[row]    
}
```